# How do i send Post request with some values of array object to my Back-end in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I Have a **vue.js** model inside which I have several input fields where I am dynamic calculating some value.

**What I am trying to do:**

When I click on submit I want to console the data in key value pair so that I can send it to back-end, The key part is I want to do it for only those fields `Having Value greater then 0`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>

  <button>Submit</button>

</div>
```

**I know how to do post request using axios the only thimg is how to get key value pairs which are grater then 0**

On click Of submit I want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For this you might use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library. Here,i add `axios` cdn link to your code snippet and demonstrate an example for hint.However, this will thrown an error,because the given `url` is not correct.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  },
  methods:{
    sendInfo(){
     console.log(this.paymentMode);
     axios.post("/your/post/url/", {
                  data: JSON.stringify(this.paymentMode)
              })
              .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log('please enter a correct url');
              });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>

  <button @click="sendInfo">Submit</button>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.js" integrity="sha256-XmdRbTre/3RulhYk/cOBUMpYlaAp2Rpo/s556u0OIKk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hey I have one small doubt

Comment: here I have 3 input fields `Swiggy`,`Uber Eats` and `Zomato`, What I want to do is when user types in swiggy or zomato it should not exceeds the net balance amount, uber eats can exceeds.Suppose `total amt=500` I put `uber eats=300` then`Bal amt is=200` so swiggy should not greater then 200, simply the swiggy and zomato can not be greater then Bal amt

Comment: It's a different question,this was not related to your main question.

Comment: Ya I know but as it is simple one but I am not getting any idea of doing that please give some idea then I will do it